# Why can't i bind a DataGrid SelectedItem to a DependencyProperty Inside a usercontrol?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

i want to bind a `DataGrid` `SelectedItem` inside a user control to a `DependencyProperty`
and this is my code:

in the user control(`DataGridControl`):

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataGridSelectedItemProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "DataGridSelectedItem"
        , typeof(object)
        , typeof(DataGridSelectorControl)
        , new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object DataGridSelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataGridSelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataGridSelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource theSource}}" 
           SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=DataGridControl,Path=DataGridSelectedItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
```

and in the viewmodel:

```
    object projectSelectedItem;
    public object ProjectSelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return projectSelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            projectSelectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ProjectSelectedItem");
        }
    }
```

and in view:

```
<MvvmCommonControl:DataGridControl  DataGridSelectedItem="{Binding ProjectSelectedItem}"  DataGridDataCollection="{Binding DataCollection}"/>
```

but it dosen't work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following in your user control:

```
 SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=DataGridControl,
```

But is you user control named `DataGridControl`?

```
<UserControl
  ...
  x:Name="DataGridControl">
```

Comment: :i didn't write the complete code here!!but i absolutely have it!!

Comment: Are you able to post the code that replicates the problem somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In Xaml use the below code

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Person,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

In ViewModel Create property for selected item.Here Customer is class which is having properties like Address,Name,OrderID.

```
private Customer selectedItem = new Customer();

        public Customer SelectedItem
        {

            get
            { return selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                selectedItem = value;
                InvokePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
             }                 
        }
```

Create one class to define dependency property

```
class DataGridSelectedItemBehaviour:DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectedItem"
        , typeof(object)
        , typeof(CustomerViewModel)
        , new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

    }
```